# android.media.AudioTrack stereo volume 0 on one channel: still very soft sound of other channel

Tags: android, volume, audiotrack

When using ***android.media.AudioTrack*** to generate a sinus sound at runtime there are two ways to set the volume to 0 in the left or right channel: with the ***setStereoVolume*** method or by generating a 0 sound on one channel. With both methods, when there is a sound in the other channel, this sound is also played at very low volume in the channel with the 0 volume.

I need no sound at all in the left or right channel when the users selects this. But it seems to be impossible. I also checked this with a few other apps that generate sound at runtime, and they have the same issue.

The issue is not isolated to specific devices, a customer of my app observed the issue, tried several different earphones/headphones, and I could reproduce it also with other headphones.

Is there a solution or is this just what it is?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware fault/headphones issue (I assume you are using headphones or some other sort of binaural speaker system).

Comment: Thanks, but it reproduces on different types of earsets and headphones. I updated the description.

Comment: Maybe the effect is common in headphones. See [here](https://www.soundonsound.com/sound-advice/q-it-normal-get-crosstalk-appearing-headphones). If this is the case, then, to answer your question, yes, you can reduce the noise by (probably) several dB by intentionally mixing a little audio into the empty channel in order to "match" the floating ground. (Would be different for different sets of headphones.)

Comment: Thanks @greeble31, I think you are right about the crosstalk effect. I tried it with a Bluetooth headset and then the issue didn't occur. Thanks for the nice reference.